# Firebase Database gradle not resolving Failed to resolve 'com.android.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Module app `Gradle`:
Updated the google repository and service from sdk too 
but this error is still there. Please someone check it out

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.norsoftbd.user.test1vaia"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
        implementation 'com.android.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
        implementation 'com.android.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
        implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
        compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

        })
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the Google Maven repository in your project level build.gradele file as shown below.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Within **build.gradle(Project)** file, add latest `google-services` and Google maven repository

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then, in your **build.gralde(Module:app)** file, add latest Firebase dependencies, apply google-services plugin and fix android support dependecies version:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.norsoftbd.user.test1vaia"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Using configuration above should work.

Comment: Ok I'll try and let u know , Thanks @AlexTa

Comment: @Md.RafsanBiswas, I have edited my answer, using provided configuration files should work, let me know if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced all "compile" with "implements" , @AlexTa I also placed the latest google services earlier.